# Simultaneous loads into single BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Given an existing table inside BigQuery, what is going to happen if multiple load jobs (all with writeDisposition = WRITE_APPEND) are loading into the same table? If all job succeeded, does that mean all data have been added to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all jobs succeeded, that mean all data have been added to the table!

Comment: And worth noting that jobs commit their results atomically, so the append operations cannot conflict or collide with one another.